# AWS ECS cluster Capacity Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I'm using this cloudformation template to create capacity providers for ECS cluster with the autoscaling group specified in the ecs capacity provider:

```
"ECSCapacityProvider": {
  "Type": "AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider",
  "Properties": {
    "AutoScalingGroupProvider": {
      "AutoScalingGroupArn": {
        "Ref": "AutoScalingGroup"
      }
    }
  },
  "DependsOn": "AutoScalingGroup"
},
"DRCluster": {
  "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster",
  "Properties": {
    "ClusterName": {
      "Ref": "WindowsECSCluster"
    },
    "CapacityProviders": "ECSCapacityProvider",
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "environment",
        "Value": "dr"
      }
    ]
  },
  "DependsOn": "ECSCapacityProvider"
}
```

But while creating the stack it resulted in the following error:

```
Model validation failed (#/CapacityProviders: expected type: JSONArray, found: String)
```

I could not find proper documentation for the capacity providers. I'm using it to attach the Auto Scaling group to the cluster, which i hope is the correct way to do so. I'm new to cloudformation, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CapacityProviders](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-cluster.html#cfn-ecs-cluster-capacityproviders) is a **List of String**, not a `String` like you have now:

```
"CapacityProviders" : "ECSCapacityProvider",
```

Therefore, in you `DRCluster` you can use the following instead:

```
"CapacityProviders" : [ {"Ref": "ECSCapacityProvider"} ],
```